# Implementing Efficient Incremental Rule Mining, working for upto 5 records, but producing timeout on large dataset

Tags: php

Input Dataset Format:(approx 100 records)

```
{"WHITE HANGING HEART T-LIGHT HOLDER":{"id":"536365 536365 536373 536375 536390 536394 536396 536401 536406","qty":138},"WHITE METAL LANTERN":{"id":"536365 536365 536373 536375 536396 536406","qty":38},"CREAM CUPID HEARTS COAT HANGER":{"id":"536365 536365 536373 536375 536396 536406","qty":48},"KNITTED UNION FLAG HOT WATER BOTTLE":{"id":"536365 536365 536373 536375 536390 536396 536406","qty":60},"RED WOOLLY HOTTIE WHITE HEART.":{"id":"536365 536365 536373 536375 536396 536406 536408","qty":40},"SET 7 BABUSHKA NESTING BOXES":{"id":"536365 536373 536375 536396 536398 536406","qty":16},"GLASS STAR FROSTED T-LIGHT HOLDER":{"id":"536365 536373 536375 536396 536406","qty":30},"HAND WARMER UNION JACK":{"id":"536366 536372 536377 536394 536399 536407 536409","qty":127},"HAND WARMER RED POLKA DOT":{"id":"536366 536372 536377 536399 536407","qty":30},"ASSORTED COLOUR BIRD ORNAMENT":{"id":"536367 536392 536395 536408","qty":88},"FELTCRAFT PRINCESS CHARLOTTE DOLL":{"id":"536367 536412 536412 536412","qty":12},"IVORY KNITTED MUG COSY ":{"id":536367,"qty":"6"},"BOX OF 6 ASSORTED COLOUR TEASPOONS":{"id":536367,"qty":"6"},"BOX OF VINTAGE JIGSAW BLOCKS ":{"id":536367,"qty":"3"},"BOX OF VINTAGE ALPHABET BLOCKS":{"id":536367,"qty":"2"},"HOME BUILDING BLOCK WORD":{"id":"536367 536388 536408","qty":9},"LOVE BUILDING BLOCK WORD":{"id":"536367 536388 536408","qty":9},"RECIPE BOX WITH METAL HEART":{"id":536367,"qty":"4"},"DOORMAT NEW ENGLAND":{"id":536367,"qty":"4"},"JAM MAKING SET WITH JARS":{"id":"536368 536385 536390","qty":24},"RED COAT RACK PARIS FASHION":{"id":536368,"qty":"3"},"YELLOW COAT RACK PARIS FASHION":{"id":536368,"qty":"3"},"BLUE COAT RACK PARIS FASHION":{"id":"536368 536408","qty":6},"BATH BUILDING BLOCK WORD":{"id":536369,"qty":"3"},"ALARM CLOCK BAKELIKE PINK":{"id":536370,"qty":"24"},"ALARM CLOCK BAKELIKE RED ":{"id":"536370 536389 536395","qty":36},"ALARM CLOCK BAKELIKE GREEN":{"id":"536370 536382 536389 536395","qty":28},"PANDA AND BUNNIES STICKER SHEET":{"id":536370,"qty":"12"},"STARS GIFT TAPE ":{"id":536370,"qty":"24"},"INFLATABLE POLITICAL GLOBE ":{"id":"536370 536382","qty":60},"VINTAGE HEADS AND TAILS CARD GAME ":{"id":"536370 536389","qty":36},"SET\/2 RED RETROSPOT TEA TOWELS ":{"id":536370,"qty":"18"},"ROUND SNACK BOXES SET OF4 WOODLAND ":{"id":"536370 536412","qty":25},"SPACEBOY LUNCH BOX ":{"id":"536370 536412","qty":25},"LUNCH BOX I LOVE LONDON":{"id":536370,"qty":"24"},"CIRCUS PARADE LUNCH BOX ":{"id":536370,"qty":"24"},"CHARLOTTE BAG DOLLY GIRL DESIGN":{"id":536370,"qty":"20"},"RED TOADSTOOL LED NIGHT LIGHT":{"id":"536370 536381 536387 536412","qty":463}," SET 2 TEA TOWELS I LOVE LONDON ":{"id":"536370 536409 536409","qty":26},"VINTAGE SEASIDE JIGSAW PUZZLES":{"id":536370,"qty":"12"},"MINI JIGSAW CIRCUS PARADE ":{"id":536370,"qty":"24"},"MINI JIGSAW SPACEBOY":{"id":536370,"qty":"24"},"MINI PAINT SET VINTAGE ":{"id":"536370 536408","qty":72},"POSTAGE":{"id":"536370 536403","qty":4},"EDWARDIAN PARASOL RED":{"id":"536373 536375 536396 536406","qty":24},"RETRO COFFEE MUGS ASSORTED":{"id":"536373 536375 536396 536406","qty":24},"SAVE THE PLANET MUG":{"id":"536373 536375 536396 536406","qty":24},"VINTAGE BILLBOARD DRINK ME MUG":{"id":"536373 536375 536396 536406","qty":24},"VINTAGE BILLBOARD LOVE\/HATE MUG":{"id":"536373 536375 536396 536406","qty":24},"WOOD 2 DRAWER CABINET WHITE FINISH":{"id":"536373 536375 536396 536401 536406","qty":11},"WOOD S\/3 CABINET ANT WHITE FINISH":{"id":"536373 536375 536396 536406","qty":16},"WOODEN PICTURE FRAME WHITE FINISH":{"id":"536373 536375 536396 536406","qty":24},"WOODEN FRAME ANTIQUE WHITE ":{"id":"536373 536375 536396 536406","qty":30},"VICTORIAN SEWING BOX LARGE":{"id":536374,"qty":"32"},"HOT WATER BOTTLE TEA AND SYMPATHY":{"id":"536376 536395 536398 536408","qty":64},"RED HANGING HEART T-LIGHT HOLDER":{"id":"536376 536408","qty":70},"JUMBO BAG PINK POLKADOT":{"id":536378,"qty":"10"},"JUMBO  BAG BAROQUE BLACK WHITE":{"id":"536378 536386","qty":110},"JUMBO BAG CHARLIE AND LOLA TOYS":{"id":"536378 536401","qty":14},"STRAWBERRY CHARLOTTE BAG":{"id":"536378 536409","qty":11},"RED 3 PIECE RETROSPOT CUTLERY SET":{"id":"536378 536408","qty":18},"BLUE 3 PIECE POLKADOT CUTLERY SET":{"id":536378,"qty":"6"},"SET\/6 RED SPOTTY PAPER PLATES":{"id":"536378 536390","qty":108},"LUNCH BAG RED RETROSPOT":{"id":"536378 536401","qty":11},"STRAWBERRY LUNCH BOX WITH CUTLERY":{"id":536378,"qty":"6"},"LUNCH BOX WITH CUTLERY RETROSPOT ":{"id":536378,"qty":"6"},"PACK OF 72 RETROSPOT CAKE CASES":{"id":"536378 536395 536404 536408","qty":192},"PACK OF 60 DINOSAUR CAKE CASES":{"id":"536378 536404","qty":48},"PACK OF 60 PINK PAISLEY CAKE CASES":{"id":"536378 536395","qty":48},"60 TEATIME FAIRY CAKE CASES":{"id":"536378 536395 536401","qty":51},"TOMATO CHARLIE+LOLA COASTER SET":{"id":536378,"qty":"6"},"CHARLIE & LOLA WASTEPAPER BIN FLORA":{"id":536378,"qty":"48"},"RED CHARLIE+LOLA PERSONAL DOORSIGN":{"id":536378,"qty":"96"},"JUMBO STORAGE BAG SUKI":{"id":"536378 536409","qty":12},"JUMBO BAG PINK VINTAGE PAISLEY":{"id":536378,"qty":"10"},"JAM MAKING SET PRINTED":{"id":"536380 536385 536390 536401 536412","qty":76},"RETROSPOT TEA SET CERAMIC 11 PC ":{"id":536381,"qty":"23"},"GIRLY PINK TOOL SET":{"id":536381,"qty":"5"},"JUMBO SHOPPER VINTAGE RED PAISLEY":{"id":"536381 536382","qty":20},"AIRLINE LOUNGE,METAL SIGN":{"id":536381,"qty":"2"},"WHITE SPOT RED CERAMIC DRAWER KNOB":{"id":536381,"qty":"6"},"RED DRAWER KNOB ACRYLIC EDWARDIAN":{"id":536381,"qty":"24"},"CLEAR DRAWER KNOB ACRYLIC EDWARDIAN":{"id":"536381 536404","qty":36},"PHOTO CLIP LINE":{"id":"536381 536381","qty":4},"FELT EGG COSY CHICKEN":{"id":536381,"qty":"1"},"PIGGY BANK RETROSPOT ":{"id":"536381 536398","qty":9},"SKULL SHOULDER BAG":{"id":536381,"qty":"10"},"COOK WITH WINE METAL SIGN ":{"id":536381,"qty":"1"},"GIN + TONIC DIET METAL SIGN":{"id":536381,"qty":"2"},"YELLOW BREAKFAST CUP AND SAUCER":{"id":536381,"qty":"1"},"PINK BREAKFAST CUP AND SAUCER ":{"id":536381,"qty":"1"},"PAPER CHAIN KIT RETROSPOT":{"id":536381,"qty":"1"},"SMALL HEART FLOWERS HOOK ":{"id":536381,"qty":"6"},"TEA TIME DES TEA COSY":{"id":536381,"qty":"2"},"FELT EGG COSY WHITE RABBIT ":{"id":536381,"qty":"1"},"ZINC WILLIE WINKIE  CANDLE STICK":{"id":536381,"qty":"1"},"CERAMIC CHERRY CAKE MONEY BANK":{"id":536381,"qty":"1"},"RETROSPOT LARGE MILK JUG":{"id":"536381 536390","qty":13},"SET OF 6 FUNKY BEAKERS":{"id":536381,"qty":"2"},"EDWARDIAN PARASOL BLACK":{"id":"536381 536396","qty":8},"EDWARDIAN PARASOL NATURAL":{"id":536381,"qty":"2"},"CERAMIC STRAWBERRY CAKE MONEY BANK":{"id":536381,"qty":"4"},"BLUE OWL SOFT TOY":{"id":536381,"qty":"1"},"BALLOON ART MAKE YOUR OWN FLOWERS":{"id":536381,"qty":"1"},"GLASS CLOCHE SMALL":{"id":536381,"qty":"3"},"GUMBALL MONOCHROME COAT RACK":{"id":536381,"qty":"36"},"DOORMAT FANCY FONT HOME SWEET HOME":{"id":"536381 536388","qty":12},"VINTAGE SNAKES & LADDERS":{"id":536382,"qty":"8"},"CHOCOLATE CALCULATOR":{"id":"536382 536408","qty":24},"RECYCLING BAG RETROSPOT ":{"id":536382,"qty":"10"},"TOY TIDY PINK POLKADOT":{"id":536382,"qty":"50"},"ANTIQUE GLASS DRESSING TABLE POT":{"id":536382,"qty":"8"},"IVORY GIANT GARDEN THERMOMETER":{"id":536382,"qty":"12"},"3 TIER CAKE TIN GREEN AND CREAM":{"id":536382,"qty":"2"},"3 TIER CAKE TIN RED AND CREAM":{"id":536382,"qty":"2"},"SET 3 WICKER OVAL BASKETS W LIDS":{"id":"536382 536385","qty":5},"WOOD BLACK BOARD ANT WHITE FINISH":{"id":536384,"qty":"3"},"COLOUR GLASS T-LIGHT HOLDER HANGING":{"id":536384,"qty":"48"},"HANGING METAL HEART LANTERN":{"id":"536384 536388","qty":24},"HANGING MEDINA LANTERN SMALL":{"id":536384,"qty":"6"},"NATURAL SLATE HEART CHALKBOARD ":{"id":536384,"qty":"12"},"HEART OF WICKER SMALL":{"id":"536384 536388 536404","qty":64},"HEART OF WICKER LARGE":{"id":536384,"qty":"40"},"WHITE LOVEBIRD LANTERN":{"id":536384,"qty":"6"},"CLASSIC METAL BIRDCAGE PLANT HOLDER":{"id":536384,"qty":"2"},"CREAM HEART CARD HOLDER":{"id":536384,"qty":"4"},"ENAMEL FLOWER JUG CREAM":{"id":536384,"qty":"3"},"ENAMEL FIRE BUCKET CREAM":{"id":"536384 536401","qty":8},"ENAMEL BREAD BIN CREAM":{"id":536384,"qty":"8"},"JUMBO BAG DOLLY GIRL DESIGN":{"id":536385,"qty":"10"},"TRADITIONAL CHRISTMAS RIBBONS":{"id":536385,"qty":"12"},"ORGANISER WOOD ANTIQUE WHITE ":{"id":536385,"qty":"2"},"LUNCH BAG DOLLY GIRL DESIGN":{"id":"536385 536401 536412","qty":15},"WHITE WIRE EGG HOLDER":{"id":536386,"qty":"36"},"JUMBO BAG RED RETROSPOT":{"id":"536386 536390 536409","qty":202},"CHILLI LIGHTS":{"id":536387,"qty":"192"},"LIGHT GARLAND BUTTERFILES PINK":{"id":536387,"qty":"192"},"WOODEN OWLS LIGHT GARLAND ":{"id":536387,"qty":"192"},"FAIRY TALE COTTAGE NIGHTLIGHT":{"id":536387,"qty":"432"},"HOME SMALL WOOD LETTERS":{"id":536388,"qty":"3"},"GINGHAM HEART  DOORSTOP RED":{"id":536388,"qty":"3"},"FIVE HEART HANGING DECORATION":{"id":536388,"qty":"6"},"ASSORTED BOTTLE TOP  MAGNETS ":{"id":536388,"qty":"12"},"FRIDGE MAGNETS US DINER ASSORTED":{"id":536388,"qty":"12"},"HOMEMADE JAM SCENTED CANDLES":{"id":"536388 536390 536400","qty":120},"FRIDGE MAGNETS LES ENFANTS ASSORTED":{"id":536388,"qty":"12"},"ROSE CARAVAN DOORSTOP":{"id":536388,"qty":"4"},"5 HOOK HANGER MAGIC TOADSTOOL":{"id":"536388 536412","qty":17},"CHRISTMAS LIGHTS 10 REINDEER":{"id":"536389 536390","qty":8},"VINTAGE UNION JACK CUSHION COVER":{"id":536389,"qty":"8"},"SET OF 3 COLOURED  FLYING DUCKS":{"id":"536389 536397","qty":54},"SET OF 3 GOLD FLYING DUCKS":{"id":536389,"qty":"4"},"RED RETROSPOT UMBRELLA":{"id":"536389 536408","qty":9},"BLACK\/BLUE POLKADOT UMBRELLA":{"id":"536389 536408","qty":6},"RED DINER WALL CLOCK":{"id":536389,"qty":"2"},"BLUE DINER WALL CLOCK":{"id":536389,"qty":"2"},"IVORY DINER WALL CLOCK":{"id":536389,"qty":"2"},"LARGE HEART MEASURING SPOONS":{"id":536389,"qty":"24"},"SMALL HEART MEASURING SPOONS":{"id":536389,"qty":"24"},"JAM JAR WITH PINK LID":{"id":536390,"qty":"48"},"JAM JAR WITH GREEN LID":{"id":536390,"qty":"48"},"ROSE COTTAGE KEEPSAKE BOX ":{"id":"536390 536412","qty":12},"HANGING HEART ZINC T-LIGHT HOLDER":{"id":536390,"qty":"144"},"PAPER CHAIN KIT VINTAGE CHRISTMAS":{"id":"536390 536402","qty":80},"DISCO BALL CHRISTMAS DECORATION":{"id":"536390 536409","qty":312},"SMALL POPCORN HOLDER":{"id":"536390 536404 536409","qty":138},"LARGE POPCORN HOLDER ":{"id":"536390 536409","qty":51},"SET\/20 RED RETROSPOT PAPER NAPKINS ":{"id":536390,"qty":"96"},"SET\/6 RED SPOTTY PAPER CUPS":{"id":536390,"qty":"48"},"POLKADOT RAIN HAT ":{"id":536390,"qty":"144"},"DELUXE SEWING KIT ":{"id":536390,"qty":"40"},"RETROSPOT HEART HOT WATER BOTTLE":{"id":"536390 536394","qty":36},"ENGLISH ROSE HOT WATER BOTTLE":{"id":"536390 536401","qty":25},"PHOTO CUBE":{"id":536390,"qty":"48"},"3 STRIPEY MICE FELTCRAFT":{"id":536392,"qty":"6"},"SET OF 6 SOLDIER SKITTLES":{"id":"536392 536408","qty":8},"TRADITIONAL WOODEN SKIPPING ROPE":{"id":536392,"qty":"12"},"WOODEN BOX OF DOMINOES":{"id":536392,"qty":"12"},"RUSTIC  SEVENTEEN DRAWER SIDEBOARD":{"id":536392,"qty":"1"},"PARTY CONES CARNIVAL ASSORTED":{"id":536392,"qty":"12"},"PARTY CONES CANDY ASSORTED":{"id":536392,"qty":"12"},"PICNIC BASKET WICKER SMALL":{"id":"536392 536401","qty":6},"STAR DECORATION PAINTED ZINC ":{"id":536392,"qty":"24"},"RETROSPOT LAMP":{"id":536393,"qty":"8"},"FANCY FONT BIRTHDAY CARD, ":{"id":536394,"qty":"24"},"HAND WARMER SCOTTY DOG DESIGN":{"id":"536394 536395 536398 536409 536409","qty":158},"HAND WARMER OWL DESIGN":{"id":"536394 536398","qty":108},"HAND WARMER RED RETROSPOT":{"id":"536394 536398","qty":108},"DOG BOWL CHASING BALL DESIGN":{"id":536394,"qty":"12"},"CLOTHES PEGS RETROSPOT PACK 24 ":{"id":536394,"qty":"48"},"HAND OVER THE CHOCOLATE   SIGN ":{"id":536394,"qty":"12"},"TRAVEL SEWING KIT":{"id":"536394 536412","qty":25},"BLACK HEART CARD HOLDER":{"id":536395,"qty":"8"},"CHICK GREY HOT WATER BOTTLE":{"id":536395,"qty":"8"},"SMALL GLASS HEART TRINKET POT":{"id":536395,"qty":"8"},"ALARM CLOCK BAKELIKE IVORY":{"id":536395,"qty":"4"},"ALARM CLOCK BAKELIKE ORANGE":{"id":536395,"qty":"8"},"HAND WARMER BIRD DESIGN":{"id":"536395 536403","qty":144},"IVORY EMBROIDERED QUILT ":{"id":"536396 536406","qty":4},"SET OF 3 BLACK FLYING DUCKS":{"id":536397,"qty":"12"},"PACK OF 12 RED RETROSPOT TISSUES ":{"id":"536398 536409","qty":36},"RED RETROSPOT MUG":{"id":536398,"qty":"6"},"BABUSHKA LIGHTS STRING OF 10":{"id":536398,"qty":"4"},"DOORMAT FAIRY CAKE":{"id":536398,"qty":"2"},"STRAWBERRY CERAMIC TRINKET BOX":{"id":536398,"qty":"12"},"PINK DOUGHNUT TRINKET POT ":{"id":536398,"qty":"12"},"SILK PURSE BABUSHKA PINK":{"id":536398,"qty":"6"},"HOT WATER BOTTLE I AM SO POORLY":{"id":536398,"qty":"8"},"CHOCOLATE HOT WATER BOTTLE":{"id":"536398 536409","qty":10},"WHITE SKULL HOT WATER BOTTLE ":{"id":"536398 536408 536409","qty":9},"SCOTTIE DOG HOT WATER BOTTLE":{"id":"536398 536409 536409","qty":11},"BIRD HOUSE HOT WATER BOTTLE":{"id":536401,"qty":"1"},"BOUDOIR SQUARE TISSUE BOX":{"id":536401,"qty":"1"},"SKULLS SQUARE TISSUE BOX":{"id":536401,"qty":"2"},"PHOTO FRAME CORNICE":{"id":"536401 536408","qty":9},"SILK PURSE BABUSHKA RED":{"id":536401,"qty":"1"},"PICTURE DOMINOES":{"id":536401,"qty":"1"},"S\/6 SEW ON CROCHET FLOWERS":{"id":536401,"qty":"1"},"SCANDINAVIAN REDS RIBBONS":{"id":"536401 536404 536412 536412 536412","qty":30},"BALLOONS  WRITING SET ":{"id":536401,"qty":"1"},"LAVENDER INCENSE IN TIN":{"id":536401,"qty":"1"},"TV DINNER TRAY VINTAGE PAISLEY":{"id":536401,"qty":"1"},"SET OF 4 ENGLISH ROSE PLACEMATS":{"id":536401,"qty":"2"},"SET OF 4 ENGLISH ROSE COASTERS":{"id":536401,"qty":"2"},"TRIPLE PHOTO FRAME CORNICE ":{"id":536401,"qty":"2"},"FAMILY PHOTO FRAME CORNICE":{"id":536401,"qty":"1"},"MIRRORED DISCO BALL ":{"id":536401,"qty":"1"},"DISCO BALL ROTATOR BATTERY OPERATED":{"id":536401,"qty":"1"},"SILVER LOOKING MIRROR":{"id":536401,"qty":"3"},"LADIES & GENTLEMEN METAL SIGN":{"id":536401,"qty":"1"},"METAL SIGN HER DINNER IS SERVED ":{"id":536401,"qty":"1"},"DOORMAT TOPIARY":{"id":536401,"qty":"1"},"BATHROOM METAL SIGN":{"id":536401,"qty":"1"},"KITCHEN METAL SIGN":{"id":536401,"qty":"1"},"TOILET METAL SIGN":{"id":536401,"qty":"2"},"METAL SIGN TAKE IT OR LEAVE IT ":{"id":536401,"qty":"4"},"GROW YOUR OWN BASIL IN ENAMEL MUG":{"id":536401,"qty":"1"},"SET\/10 PINK POLKADOT PARTY CANDLES":{"id":536401,"qty":"1"},"SET 20 NAPKINS FAIRY CAKES DESIGN ":{"id":536401,"qty":"1"},"SET OF 6 T-LIGHTS SNOWMEN":{"id":536401,"qty":"1"},"SET OF 6 T-LIGHTS SANTA":{"id":536401,"qty":"1"},"SET OF 9 HEART SHAPED BALLOONS":{"id":536401,"qty":"2"},"SANDWICH BATH SPONGE":{"id":"536401 536409","qty":5},"APPLE BATH SPONGE":{"id":536401,"qty":"1"},"STRAWBERRY BATH SPONGE ":{"id":536401,"qty":"1"},"BLACK PIRATE TREASURE CHEST":{"id":536401,"qty":"2"},"STAR PORTABLE TABLE LIGHT ":{"id":536401,"qty":"2"},"SNOWFLAKE PORTABLE TABLE LIGHT ":{"id":536401,"qty":"2"},"PINK OVAL JEWELLED MIRROR":{"id":536401,"qty":"1"},"RETROSPOT CIGAR BOX MATCHES ":{"id":536401,"qty":"1"},"COSY HOUR GIANT TUBE MATCHES":{"id":"536401 536408","qty":14},"JAZZ HEARTS PURSE NOTEBOOK":{"id":536401,"qty":"9"},"CANDLEHOLDER PINK HANGING HEART":{"id":536401,"qty":"3"},"ASSORTED COLOUR MINI CASES":{"id":536401,"qty":"1"},"LUNCH BAG SPACEBOY DESIGN ":{"id":"536401 536412","qty":5},"LUNCH BAG WOODLAND":{"id":536401,"qty":"1"},"LUNCH BAG PINK POLKADOT":{"id":536401,"qty":"1"},"GUMBALL COAT RACK":{"id":536401,"qty":"5"},"BLUE NEW BAROQUE CANDLESTICK CANDLE":{"id":"536401 536409","qty":6},"PINK NEW BAROQUECANDLESTICK CANDLE":{"id":"536401 536409","qty":4},"FAIRY CAKE FLANNEL ASSORTED COLOUR":{"id":536401,"qty":"9"},"BREAD BIN DINER STYLE PINK":{"id":536401,"qty":"1"},"TEA TIME TABLE CLOTH":{"id":536401,"qty":"1"},"HOT WATER BOTTLE BABUSHKA ":{"id":"536402 536412","qty":39},"HEART IVORY TRELLIS SMALL":{"id":536404,"qty":"24"},"PINK DRAWER KNOB ACRYLIC EDWARDIAN":{"id":536404,"qty":"12"},"GREEN DRAWER KNOB ACRYLIC EDWARDIAN":{"id":536404,"qty":"12"},"BLUE DRAWER KNOB ACRYLIC EDWARDIAN":{"id":536404,"qty":"12"},"SET 6 FOOTBALL CELEBRATION CANDLES":{"id":536404,"qty":"12"},"SET OF 6 GIRLS CELEBRATION CANDLES":{"id":536404,"qty":"12"},"ROMANTIC PINKS RIBBONS ":{"id":536404,"qty":"12"},"BRIGHT BLUES RIBBONS ":{"id":536404,"qty":"12"},"CHOCOLATE BOX RIBBONS ":{"id":536404,"qty":"12"},"PARTY INVITES FOOTBALL":{"id":536404,"qty":"12"},"PARTY INVITES JAZZ HEARTS":{"id":536404,"qty":"12"},"PARTY INVITES SPACEMAN":{"id":536404,"qty":"12"},"SET OF 3 BUTTERFLY COOKIE CUTTERS":{"id":536404,"qty":"12"},"SET OF 3 HEART COOKIE CUTTERS":{"id":536404,"qty":"12"},"3 PIECE SPACEBOY COOKIE CUTTER SET":{"id":"536404 536408","qty":18},"PACK OF 72 SKULL CAKE CASES":{"id":536404,"qty":"24"},"PACK OF 60 SPACEBOY CAKE CASES":{"id":536404,"qty":"24"},"72 SWEETHEART FAIRY CAKE CASES":{"id":536404,"qty":"24"},"LUNCH BAG SUKI  DESIGN ":{"id":"536404 536412","qty":13},"LUNCH BAG CARS BLUE":{"id":"536404 536412","qty":13},"LUNCH BAG  BLACK SKULL.":{"id":"536404 536412","qty":13},"HEART IVORY TRELLIS LARGE":{"id":536404,"qty":"24"},"SET\/5 RED RETROSPOT LID GLASS BOWLS":{"id":536405,"qty":"128"},"MAGIC DRAWING SLATE DINOSAUR":{"id":536408,"qty":"24"},"MAGIC DRAWING SLATE BAKE A CAKE ":{"id":536408,"qty":"24"},"12 PENCILS TALL TUBE SKULLS":{"id":536408,"qty":"12"},"RED  HARMONICA IN BOX ":{"id":536408,"qty":"12"},"BLUE HARMONICA IN BOX ":{"id":536408,"qty":"12"},"SKULLS  WATER TRANSFER TATTOOS ":{"id":536408,"qty":"12"},"PACK 3 BOXES BIRD PANNETONE ":{"id":536408,"qty":"12"},"SET OF 20 KIDS COOKIE CUTTERS":{"id":536408,"qty":"12"},"10 COLOUR SPACEBOY PEN":{"id":536408,"qty":"24"},"VICTORIAN GLASS HANGING T-LIGHT":{"id":536408,"qty":"12"},"SINGLE HEART ZINC T-LIGHT HOLDER":{"id":536408,"qty":"12"},"HANGING METAL STAR LANTERN":{"id":536408,"qty":"12"},"SILVER HANGING T-LIGHT HOLDER":{"id":536408,"qty":"6"},"DOORMAT RED RETROSPOT":{"id":536408,"qty":"2"},"DOORMAT HEARTS":{"id":536408,"qty":"2"},"NATURAL SLATE RECTANGLE CHALKBOARD":{"id":536408,"qty":"12"},"LOVEBIRD HANGING DECORATION WHITE ":{"id":536408,"qty":"12"},"PENS ASSORTED FUNNY FACE":{"id":536408,"qty":"36"},"CARD CIRCUS PARADE":{"id":536408,"qty":"12"},"WRAP COWBOYS  ":{"id":536408,"qty":"25"},"AIRLINE BAG VINTAGE TOKYO 78":{"id":536408,"qty":"4"},"SET OF 72 RETROSPOT PAPER  DOILIES":{"id":536408,"qty":"12"},"PLASTERS IN TIN SKULLS":{"id":536408,"qty":"12"},"SLEEPING CAT ERASERS":{"id":536408,"qty":"30"},"CARD BIRTHDAY COWBOY":{"id":536408,"qty":"12"},"PACK 3 BOXES CHRISTMAS PANNETONE":{"id":536408,"qty":"12"},"ROTATING SILVER ANGELS T-LIGHT HLDR":{"id":536408,"qty":"6"},"RIBBON REEL MAKING SNOWMEN ":{"id":536408,"qty":"10"},"4 TRADITIONAL SPINNING TOPS":{"id":536408,"qty":"12"},"BAG 500g SWIRLY MARBLES":{"id":536408,"qty":"12"},"5 STRAND GLASS NECKLACE CRYSTAL":{"id":"536409 536409 536409","qty":6},"SQUARECUSHION COVER PINK UNION FLAG":{"id":536409,"qty":"1"},"SPACEBOY CHILDRENS EGG CUP":{"id":536409,"qty":"1"},"FELTCRAFT CUSHION OWL":{"id":"536409 536412","qty":4},"BLACK CANDELABRA T-LIGHT HOLDER":{"id":"536409 536409","qty":6},"TOY TIDY DOLLY GIRL DESIGN":{"id":536409,"qty":"1"},"SET 12 LAVENDER  BOTANICAL T-LIGHTS":{"id":536409,"qty":"1"},"UNION JACK FLAG LUGGAGE TAG":{"id":"536409 536409","qty":2},"RED HEART LUGGAGE TAG":{"id":536409,"qty":"1"},"RED GLASS TASSLE BAG CHARM":{"id":536409,"qty":"1"},"CLEAR ACRYLIC FACETED BANGLE":{"id":536409,"qty":"1"},"DOORMAT UNION JACK GUNS AND ROSES":{"id":536409,"qty":"1"},"VANILLA SCENT CANDLE JEWELLED BOX":{"id":536409,"qty":"1"},"FULL ENGLISH BREAKFAST PLATE":{"id":536409,"qty":"1"},"MAGIC DRAWING SLATE CIRCUS PARADE  ":{"id":536409,"qty":"1"},"CHRISTMAS HANGING HEART WITH BELL":{"id":536409,"qty":"1"},"CAKE STAND VICTORIAN FILIGREE MED":{"id":536409,"qty":"1"},"PAISLEY PATTERN  STICKERS":{"id":536409,"qty":"6"},"FLOWERS  STICKERS":{"id":536409,"qty":"6"},"BLACK LOVE BIRD CANDLE":{"id":536409,"qty":"12"},"PARTY TIME PENCIL ERASERS":{"id":536409,"qty":"28"},"PINK UNION JACK  LUGGAGE TAG":{"id":536409,"qty":"1"},"6 RIBBONS ELEGANT CHRISTMAS ":{"id":536409,"qty":"1"},"AGED GLASS SILVER T-LIGHT HOLDER":{"id":536409,"qty":"12"},"BOOM BOX SPEAKER GIRLS":{"id":536409,"qty":"1"},"6 RIBBONS SHIMMERING PINKS ":{"id":536409,"qty":"1"},"JUMBO BAG OWLS":{"id":536409,"qty":"1"},"OWL DOORSTOP":{"id":536409,"qty":"1"},"PAINTED METAL STAR WITH HOLLY BELLS":{"id":536409,"qty":"3"},"PAINTED METAL HEART WITH HOLLY BELL":{"id":536409,"qty":"3"},"ANGEL DECORATION STARS ON DRESS":{"id":536409,"qty":"6"},"JUMBO BAG STRAWBERRY":{"id":536409,"qty":"1"},"STRAWBERRY SHOPPER BAG":{"id":536409,"qty":"1"},"ROUND SNACK BOXES SET OF 4 FRUITS ":{"id":536412,"qty":"1"},"ROUND SNACK BOXES SET OF 4 SKULLS":{"id":"536412 536412","qty":2},"DOLLY GIRL LUNCH BOX":{"id":536412,"qty":"1"},"GREEN POLKADOT PLATE ":{"id":536412,"qty":"1"},"BLUE POLKADOT PLATE ":{"id":536412,"qty":"1"},"RED RETROSPOT PLATE ":{"id":536412,"qty":"1"},"PINK  POLKADOT PLATE ":{"id":536412,"qty":"1"},"FELTCRAFT DOLL MOLLY":{"id":"536412 536412 536412","qty":4},"FELTCRAFT CHRISTMAS FAIRY":{"id":"536412 536412","qty":4},"SET OF 3 NOTEBOOKS IN PARCEL":{"id":"536412 536412","qty":6},"RED RETROSPOT TAPE":{"id":536412,"qty":"10"},"COSY SLIPPER SHOES SMALL  RED ":{"id":"536412 536412 536412","qty":8},"6 RIBBONS RUSTIC CHARM":{"id":"536412 536412 536412","qty":10},"12 DAISY PEGS IN WOOD BOX":{"id":"536412 536412 536412 536412 536412","qty":8},"5 HOOK HANGER RED MAGIC TOADSTOOL":{"id":"536412 536412 536412","qty":10},"CHRISTMAS CRAFT TREE TOP ANGEL":{"id":"536412 536412","qty":2},"CHRISTMAS CRAFT LITTLE FRIENDS":{"id":"536412 536412","qty":3},"COSY SLIPPER SHOES SMALL GREEN":{"id":536412,"qty":"2"},"FELTCRAFT DOLL ROSIE":{"id":536412,"qty":"2"},"FELTCRAFT DOLL EMILY":{"id":536412,"qty":"2"},"FELTCRAFT PRINCESS OLIVIA DOLL":{"id":536412,"qty":"2"},"REX CASH+CARRY JUMBO SHOPPER":{"id":536412,"qty":"1"},"FELTCRAFT CUSHION RABBIT":{"id":536412,"qty":"3"},"FELTCRAFT CUSHION BUTTERFLY":{"id":"536412 536412","qty":4},"TOTE BAG I LOVE LONDON":{"id":"536412 536412","qty":14},"FOLDING UMBRELLA PINKWHITE POLKADOT":{"id":536412,"qty":"1"},"FOLDING UMBRELLA CREAM POLKADOT":{"id":536412,"qty":"1"},"FOLDING UMBRELLA WHITE\/RED POLKADOT":{"id":536412,"qty":"1"}}
```

The above dataset is passed to generateItemsets.php file that generates frequent item

```
<?php
    set_time_limit(0);

    $res = $_POST['res'];
    $res = json_decode($res,true);

    $temp = array();

    do{

    $j = 0;
    foreach ($res as $key => $value) {
        $temp[$j] = $key;
        $j++;
    }
    $len = count($res);

    $final = join_it($res,$temp);
    //var_dump($final);
    if(empty($final)){
        print_r("Frequent Itemsets:");
        foreach ($res as $key => $value) {
            print_r($key."<br>");
        }
        exit();
    }
    else{
        unset($res);
        $res = array();
        $res = array_merge($res, $final);
        // var_dump($res);
    }

}while(!empty($final));


    function join_it($data,$temp){
         unset($final);
         // var_dump($temp);
         $final = array();
         if($GLOBALS['len'] == 1){
            return $final;
         }
        for($i=0;$i<$GLOBALS['len']-1;$i++)
        {
            $flag = false;
            //$const = $temp[$i];
            foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                if($flag==false){
                    if($key==$temp[$i]){
                        $flag = true;
                    }
                }
                else{
                    //Perform Join Here
                     $const_arr = explode(";", $temp[$i]);
                     $var_arr = explode(";", $key);


                     $str1 = explode(" ", $data[$temp[$i]]['id']);

                     $str2 = explode(" ", $data[$key]['id']);
                     $val_inter = array_intersect($str1, $str2);
                     $str = implode(" ", $val_inter);
                     $const = implode(";",array_unique(array_merge($const_arr,$var_arr)));
                     if(!array_key_exists($const, $final))
                     {
                     if($str!=""){

                     $x = array($const=>array("id"=>$str));
                     $final = array_merge($final, $x);
                     //$GLOBALS['final'] = array_merge($GLOBALS['final'] , $x);
                    }
                }
                }
            }
        }
        return $final;
    }



?>
```

It is working fine when number of records are very less, but I will be working with huge datasets; It is not working even when there are 50 records. I am making an ajax call to generateItemsets.php file. I am working on my final year project that is based on incremental mining.
In generateItemsets.php file, I am creating a function that generates n+1-order itemsets when I provide n-order itemsets. And I am calling the function until I am getting returned value from function as empty array. Once i find that returned value from function is empty, I am printing the previously updated itemsets that have been stored into $res array.
My algorithm is taking a lot of time for even small amount of datasets. 
Please help me! I am unsure of how to proceed!

Comment: `join_it` function is not included in your code.

Comment: @hcoat it is there just scroll down

Comment: My bad. I must be tired.

Comment: I tried to take a closer look but  running `$res = json_decode($_POST['res']); print_r("Frequent Itemsets:"); foreach ($res as $key => $value) { print_r($key."<br>");}` outputs the exact same result as all of your code, so it's hard to see what you are going for, plus I am tired.

Comment: No, it does not produce same result as you mentioned.. I am not just printing key of $res, I am performing join operation as in case similar to apriori algorithm to generate frequent itemsets.. @hcoat